# iOS NSString stringWithUTF8String / NSString initWithCString wrong utf8 decoding

Tags: objective-c, c, string, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm reading a binary file, with some text fields inside of it.

The original field value is `"asdf è"` (i cannot change the binary file encoding)

The UTF-8 encoding would be `"asdf \xc3\xa8"`

What i'm reading is instead `"asdf \xc3\x83\xc2\xa8"` so the `NSString stringWithUTF8String:` or `initWithCString` method gives to me `"asdf Ã¨"`

How to get back the right `"asdf è"` value?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is really a strange "encoding" that you read from the binary file.

- `C3 A8` is the UTF-8 sequence for `U+00C3` ("Ã")
- `C2 A8` it the UTF-8 sequence for `U+00A8` ("¨")
- The lower bytes of these Unicodes `C3 A8` are the UTF-8 sequence for `U+00E8` ("è")

The following "trick" uses the ISO Latin 1 encoding to convert the Characters
`U+00C3 U+00A8` to the bytes `C3 A8`:

```
char *s = "\xc3\x83\xc2\xa8";
NSString *s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:s length:strlen(s) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", s1);   // Ã¨
NSData *d = [s1 dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", d);    // <c3a8>
NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", s2);   // è
```